# An attribute of the algebra of upper triangle matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, modules

Let $A \leq K^{ n \times n}$ be the algebra of upper triangular matrices. Prove, that with the usage of $I_{11}, ..., I_{nn}$ idempotent elements (where $I_{ii}$ means that the $n \times n$ matrix only has $a_{ii}=1$, except that, all of its' elements are $0$), $A_A$ splits up as the direct sum of indecomposable modules, but these modules aren't all simple.
What is the dimension of the direct summands?

I simply have no idea how to approach this problem.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just take what you're given:

Look at $A\cong \oplus I_{ii}A$, and look at the endomorphism ring of $I_{ii}A$.

It is isomorphic to $I_{ii}AI_{ii}$, which is isomorphic to the ring your entries come from (which I presume is a field.)

This is enough to say that $I_{ii}A$ is indecomposable, but you can easily check a couple to see which ones are not simple.

Comment: Can you help me out a bit? I am not sure that I understand why the isomoprhisms you mentioned are actually true,

Comment: @Atvin Which isomorphism?

Comment: Basically all of them :)

Comment: @Atvin For $\oplus I_{ii}A$, you should just look at what the sets look like. It will be obvious why it's an isomorphism.

Comment: @Atvin The other one isn't as obvious. For any idempotent $e$, show that $eRe\cong End(eR)$ when you associate each $ere$ with the left-multiplication map it induces on $eR$. Injectivity should be obvious (what does $ere(e)=0$ imply about $ere$?) Hint for surjectivity: suppose $f:eR\to eR$. Then $f(e)=es$ for some $s$. Notice also $f(e)=f(e^2)=f(e)e=ese$. Then compute $f(er)$ in general.